# cannot load such file -- ntlm/http (LoadError) - ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm using ntlm-http gem to verify Windows authentication. This works fine when I run in my test Ruby code, but when I implement it using Cucumber it complains of:

```
cannot load such file -- ntlm/http (LoadError)
```

Can any one help me with this please?

Comment: It's been a month since you asked... did you manage to figure it out? I've just hit a similar problem... Am using RVM, 'ruby-ntlm' appears when I run `gem list`, but can't require it under cucumber, rspec or irb...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
require 'net/ntlm_http'
```

Worked for me!